# what does this countdown-timer.js do? carousels not working when my computer's date is more than feb 28 2016

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer, countdown

i am building a website by customizing a template.
It has carousel and gallery lightbox. but they only work until feb 28 2016.

When my computer's date is past feb like march 1 2016. those carousel or gallery lightbox stops working. i am freaking out. i think something is done by this countdown-timer.js file which contains following code: but i only understand a little of javascript. Please anyone, if you can tell me what this code is doing to my site, i would be grateful:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.countdown = function(options, callback) {

        //custom 'this' selector
        thisEl = $(this);

        //array of custom settings
        var settings = { 
            'date': null,
            'format': null
        };

        //append the settings array to options
        if(options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        //main countdown function
        function countdown_proc() {

            eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;
            currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);

            if(eventDate <= currentDate) {
                callback.call(this);
                clearInterval(interval);
            }

            seconds = eventDate - currentDate;

            days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)); //calculate the number of days
            seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24; //update the seconds variable with no. of days removed

            hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
            seconds -= hours * 60 * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of hours removed

            minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            seconds -= minutes * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of minutes removed

            //conditional Ss
            if (days == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("days"); }
            if (hours == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hour"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours"); }
            if (minutes == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minute"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minutes"); }
            if (seconds == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("second"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("seconds"); }

            //logic for the two_digits ON setting
            if(settings['format'] == "on") {
                days = (String(days).length >= 2) ? days : "0" + days;
                hours = (String(hours).length >= 2) ? hours : "0" + hours;
                minutes = (String(minutes).length >= 2) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
                seconds = (String(seconds).length >= 2) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
            }

            //update the countdown's html values.
            if(!isNaN(eventDate)) {
                thisEl.find(".days").text(days);
                thisEl.find(".hours").text(hours);
                thisEl.find(".minutes").text(minutes);
                thisEl.find(".seconds").text(seconds);
            } else { 
                alert("Invalid date. Here's an example: 12 Tuesday 2012 17:30:00");
                clearInterval(interval); 
            }
        }

        //run the function
        countdown_proc();

        //loop the function
        interval = setInterval(countdown_proc, 1000);

    }
}) (jQuery);
```

Comment: Maybe you can add more information about other plugins you have etc. And maybe any console error messages that pop up after the page is refreshed with the time changed

Comment: doesn't seem like there is any direct manipulation done by this javascript - maybe provide the website with malfunctioning carousel?

Comment: the screenshots are :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2jSaubHCpYFeHVHeldIeGRMQzQ/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2jSaubHCpYFRlhSSDF5bkVzS2s/view?usp=sharing

the problem is: when my computer's date is feb 28 2016 or before than that, everything works fine. but not when the date is past that.